# jQuery fails to receive data from Rails 3 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a very weird situation that is driving me nuts. I have a rails app that sends a simple string to jQuery and prints it out. Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.bid a').livequery('click', function() {
        obj = jQuery(this);
        jQuery.post(obj.attr('href'), function(data) {
            alert(data)
        });
        return false;
    });
    })
```

Rails Controller:

```
def send_message
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
          @res_str = "nobids"
          render :json => @res_str
      end 
    end
end
```

Like that, it works ok, it shows an alert with the string "nobids". However, if I want to send any other string, lets say "nobidss", it fails! It makes no sense at all!

What could be happening?

Comment: In the network console of Chrome's developers tools I can see that the request succeeds with code 200 ok. The response is just as expected. Anyways it doesn't call the function after success. Everything is in the same server so I can discard "Same Origin Policy" from causing this (how would it succeed when the string is "nobids" anyways?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a rookie mistake!

If you render :json you have to convert the response message to json, ie: @response.to_json.

Also, in the html, the href has to end in .json, and in the controller you have to respond to format.json too.

I cannot tell why it was succeeding with the string "nobids" anyways.

It works beautifull now